# PHP to populate drop down list with specific dates

Tags: php, forms, strtotime

I'm looking to populate a drop down list in a form with dates of the next 4 Fridays and Saturdays. This is for a reservation system of sorts. I'm thinking I should be using the `strtotime` function.
However, I'd like to order this drop down menu so that if the user tries the operation on a Saturday, the first saturday option is displayed first. 
I was thinking of populating the menu with

```
strtotime('friday');
strtotime('saturday');
strtotime('+1 weeks friday');
strtotime('+1 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+2 weeks friday');
strtotime('+2 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+3 weeks friday');
strtotime('+3 weeks saturday');
```

but obviously this wouldn't work if used it on a Saturday. (i.e. next friday which is next week will be displayed above the current saturday). Can anyone suggest a way to get around this?

Sorry if that question is rambling but it's been a long day :p

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I'm looking for a way to automagically change the list ordering to

```
strtotime('saturday');
strtotime('+1 weeks friday');
strtotime('+1 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+2 weeks friday');
strtotime('+2 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+3 weeks friday');
strtotime('+3 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+4 weeks friday');
```

if the user runs the script on a saturday. (i.e. maintain 8 items in the list with the first one being the next available date).

Comment: How about adding a "today" option if today is friday/saturday? That'd leave the option for next friday/saturday (today + 7 days) intact.

Comment: try the calendar class of php makes it easy for u

Comment: Ah I see, so add an if statement checking for whether `today==next friday || today == next saturday` sort of thing? I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way to maintain 8 options in the list but just select the starting point based on the current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this string is getting passed to strtotime()?

Don't use "next friday" and "next saturday". Saying "next friday" always gets you the next Friday *after* today. Just use "friday" instead, it returns the same as "today" if today is Friday, otherwise it returns the same as "next friday".

To get the next four Fridays and Saturdays do this:

```
strtotime('friday');
strtotime('saturday');
strtotime('+1 weeks friday');
strtotime('+1 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+2 weeks friday');
strtotime('+2 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+3 weeks friday');
strtotime('+3 weeks saturday');
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still wondering though how to display `strtotime('saturday');
strtotime('+1 weeks friday');
strtotime('+1 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+2 weeks friday');
strtotime('+2 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+3 weeks friday');
strtotime('+3 weeks saturday');
strtotime('+4 weeks friday');` if running the script on a Saturday. (Aside from a bunch of if statements that is).

Comment: The above code will still work. If today is Saturday then "friday" refers to "next friday" and "+1 weeks friday" refers to the next Friday after that.

Comment: I understand that but I'm asking how to order the output. For example if the user calls the script on a Saturday, then the "saturday" variable will be the current date and the 2nd option whereas the 1st option would be a date in the future thus the ordering would be wrong. I know it's only aesthetic but it's still worth considering.

Comment: Well, as you can see the "english" that `strtotime()` understands isn't quite intuitive English. The string "+1 weeks friday" doesn't strictly mean "the Friday of next week", it means "the soonest Friday plus one week", which on a Saturday will be 13 days in the future not six days like you want. To avoid any confusion, I would use the above list to build an array of timestamps, sort the array, and then output them as absolute calendar dates.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought you meant. I just wasn't entirely positive about that array and sort bit. Thanks!