# Get N number of consecutive Thursdays from a conditionally determined starting date

Tags: php, loops, date

I'm trying to get date for only Thursday in every week base on total week input in loop.

Example I put for 4 weeks from now, means it will take the Thursday date from current week until next 4 weeks.

What I've done so far:

```
$totalWeek = 4;
for($i=0; $i<$totalWeek ; $i++) {
    $getDateEveryThursday = strtotime("next Thursday");
    $convertDate = date('d-m-Y', $getDateEveryThursday);
}
```

Expected result if current datetime is before Thursday 08:00PM:

```
21-SEP-2023
28-SEP-2023
05-OCT-2023
12-OCT-2023
```

Also, if the current datetime is Thursday and equal to or after 08:01PM, the dates should be:

```
28-SEP-2023
05-OCT-2023
12-OCT-2023
19-OCT-2023
```

Comment: Why do you want it to switch at 08:00PM?

Comment: Topically related: [Get weekly dates on Monday, Friday, X times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76198456/2943403) and [Get the date of all Fridays in a given year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395706/2943403) and of course you can just add `+$i weeks` in your `strtotime()` call like [PHP to populate drop down list with specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6189342/2943403)  By the way, where is the mention of the `8pm` cutoff in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Given the code you have, you could do:

```
$weeks = 4;
$date = "";
for($weekNo = 0; $weekNo < $weeks; $weekNo++) {
    $thursday = strtotime("next Thursday " . $date);
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $thursday);
    echo $date . "\n";
}
```

Which would currently return:

```
21-09-2023
28-09-2023
05-10-2023
12-10-2023
```

The only real change is that I feed the date you get back into the `strtotime()` function to indicate to that function where to start.

See demo: https://3v4l.org/kQKm6

If you want to add the shift to the next Thursday, on a Thursday after 8:00 PM, you need to add a bit to skip a week forward, like this:

```
$weeks = 4;
$date = "";
if ((date("l") == "Thursday") && (date('H') >= 20)) {
    $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("next Thursday"));
}
for($weekNo = 0; $weekNo < $weeks; $weekNo++) {
    $thursday = strtotime("next Thursday " . $date);
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $thursday);
    echo $date . "\n";
}
```

See demo: https://3v4l.org/tfBU1